# Metapost for loop of a list

Tags: loops, metapost

Suppose I have a array of path `path pat[];` I try to define a function like this:

```
def drawpaths(expr plists)=
  for p in plists:
    pickup defaultpen;
    draw pat[p];
  endfor
enddef
```

so that I can draw the path `0,2,3` simply by call `drawpaths(0,2,3)`.

Unfortunately, metapost don't support for loops of a list, is there any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course Metapost supports loops over lists.  Here in ConTeXt:

```
\startMPpage
path pat[];
pat[0] := (0,0) -- (10,10);
pat[1] := (0,0) -- (10,20);
pat[2] := (0,0) -- (10,30);

def drawpaths(text plists) =
    for p = plists:
        pickup defaultpen;
        draw pat[p];
    endfor
enddef;

drawpaths(0,1,2);
\stopMPpage
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot! We can also move the definition to the very beginning of the code and set the variable p as a local one.